# Rails : Custom Callbacks at Runtime?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I'm wondering if it's possible to endow a model in Rails with custom callback code at runtime?

I have a situation where I have many "Nodes" that are creating "Events", and each node *might* need to run specific callbacks on the event.  For example, one node may need to call out to a third-party API for extra data before it can create an event.  Another node may need to send an email to it's owner after creating an event.

In my head, it makes sense to set up something like this when I do a "POST /node/4/event":

```
class Nodes::EventsController < ApplicationController
  def create

    # ...security checks in place and we have a @node

    if @node.requires_custom_callbacks?
      # Load the file with callbacks for @node.id,
      # something like Node4EventExtensions
      # Apply Node4EventExtensions to the Event model
    end

    Event.create 

  end
end
```

This would keep Node-specific code out of my Event model, and allow me to build/test custom node extensions separately.  Is this something that's possible to pull off in Rails?  Is there another way I should be looking at this?

Comment: Are you trying to describe a workflow engine?

Comment: I had to look up workflow engine.  I don't think that's quite what I'm looking for. Some of my Nodes have specific custom requirements around posting Events. Node20 might need a before_create callback to ping a third party API for permission and Node22 might need an after_create to send an email when successful.
My thinking was that I could create something like a "Node20Event" Module and dynamically include it to Event so that Event would behave like a Node20Event for the duration of the request. I haven't found a way to pull that off.

Comment: then you might need to create subclasses of your model.

Answer (score 0):

I've worked it out this way, and it seems to be holding up, at least for my initial custom requirements.  Here's a stripped down version of how it's connected:

My controller calls a class method on Event:

```
class Nodes::EventsController < ApplicationController
  def create

    # ...security checks in place and we have a @node

    if @node.requires_custom_callbacks?
        Event.extend_for_node(node.id)
    end
    Event.create 
  end
end
```

Event model then includes a Module for that Node:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.extend_for_node(node_id)
    include "#Node{node_id}Event".constantize
  end

  ...

end
```

The module will contain the the extra requirements:

```
module Node20Event extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    before_create :im_here
  end

  def im_here
    throw "HERE"
  end

end
```